# Отсчет количества лет, месяцев и дней из числа

Tags: c#, время, дата

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста с задачкой, которую нужно написать на c#: 
Дана сумма денег = 15000 $, которую нужно собрать.

В день я собираю например 4 $.

Как посчитать сколько нужно лет, месяцев и дней, чтобы ее собрать? 
(Учитываю високосный год и разное количество дней в месяцах).

Отсчет дней и месяцев можно считать с реального текущего дня. (Например со 2 октября 2017 года).

Comment: В чем же именно помочь?

Comment: Посчитать, сколько надо дней на это. Взять текущую дату как дату А, добавить к ней дни - получить дату Б. Вычесть из Б дату А и поглядеть на результат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать объект класса timespan

```
        var nested = 15000;
        var salaryPerDay = 4;
        var nestedDays = (int)Math.Floor(nested /(float) salaryPerDay);

        var dayStart = System.DateTime.Now;
        var dayEnd = dayStart + TimeSpan.FromDays(nestedDays);

        var days = dayEnd.Day - dayStart.Day;

        var daysInStartMonth = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(dayStart.Year, dayStart.Month);

        var monthShift = 0;
        if (days < 0)
        {
            days += daysInStartMonth;
            monthShift = -1;
        }
        var month = dayEnd.Month - dayStart.Month + monthShift;
        var yearShift = 0;
        if (month < 0)
        {
            month += 12;
            yearShift = -1;
        }
        var years = dayEnd.Year - dayStart.Year + yearShift;


        var timeLeft = dayEnd - dayStart;

        Console.WriteLine($"Start {dayStart.ToString("d")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"End   {dayEnd.ToString("d")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Years:{years} Month:{month} Days:{days}");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Идея хорошая,  вот только у TimeSpan нет TotalYears и TotalMounth

Comment: А точно, нужно timeSpan.Years timeSpan.Month%12+1

Comment: И такого тоже нет

Comment: Да действительно нет, по памяти писал. Исправил решение.

Comment: Отлично, а как сделать так, чтобы он выводил:  "Остался: 1 год, 2 месяца, 23 дня"?

Comment: Там нужно склонять слова а это уже отдельная задача.

Answer (score 0):

```
double sum = 15000;
double moneyPerDay = 4;
var result = new DateTime().Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(sum / moneyPerDay).Subtract(DateTime.Now));
int years = result.Year;
int months = result.Month;
int days = result.Day;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;

  DateTime newDay = thisDay+3750;

int days=  newDay.Day-thisDay.Day;
int month=newDay.Month-thisDay.Month;
if (days<0) 
{
   days +=30;
   month--;

int years =newDay.Year-thisDay.Year;
if (month<0) years--;
```